# Instanciate new Component in Vue 3 with Data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, instantiation

I program a little chess-like game with Vue
I am trying to instanciate new Pieces with data.
Basicly I want do this (expressed in a different Language):
`array.add(new Piece(data))`

currently I'm doing this:

```js
const piece = {
  name: 'piece',
  template: "<div> ... "
  data: function () {
    return {
      id: null,
      //data
      isInit: false,
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    game.register(this)
  },
  methods: {
    isInstanciated: function () {
      return this.isInit
    },
    init: function (id, data) { 
    this.isInit = true
    this.id = id 
     //initialize, etc
    }
}
const app = {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    piece
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      pieceClassArray: [],
      pieceObjectArray: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register: function (pieceInstance) {
      this.pieceObjectArray.push(pieceInstance)
    },

    instanciatePiece: function (id, data) {
      
      this.pieceClassArray.push(piece)

      let that = this
      setTimeout(function () {
        for (let pieceInstance of that.pieceObjectArray) {
          if (pieceInstance.isInstanciated() === false) {
            pieceInstance.init(id, data)
            break
          }
        }
      }, 50);

    },
}
const game = Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app')

// !!!!somewhere in the html !!!!
<piece v-for="piece in pieceClassArray"></piece>
```

---

Explanation of my ridiculous code:
I am starting with the `instanciatePiece()` function
`this.pieceClassArray.push(piece)` makes a new component due to this wierd Vue functionality `<piece v-for="piece in pieceClassArray"></piece>`
after that the `piece.mounted` calls `game.register(this)`
which collects the new Object reference and stores it in a `pieceObjectArray`

-> in a time delayed function is then iterated over `pieceObjectArray` to find new, unitialized Pieces to initialize with the given data

---

**Its working, but I am very sure, that I am using Vue wrong**
How should a Component be instanciated in Vue3 ?

When i tried instanciating with Vue.createApp(piece) i couldn't pass any data,
and when i created the second one, both diappeared for unknown reasons

Comment: If I'm reading this right you want each piece is register itself in a 'central' array that tracks pieces? The usual way to do this would be to use a global store of some kind, using Vuex or similar.

Comment: @match Yes, the game should have the references in an Array. I didnt know i needed another framework for that. Thanks for the tip.